# difference between" if(condition) int++" and int += "Convert.Toint32(condition)"

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

these two ways of incrementing a value by one

```
if (Condition) int++;
```

and

```
int+= Convert.Toint32(Condition);
```

so is there and benefit to write in one way or another or are they basically the same?

Comment: One is easier to read than the other.

Comment: If I saw that second one in a code review, I'd make the developer change it. But that's me.

Comment: One is peforming a branch, the other a cast.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'd make them change the *first* one also; statements for an `if` have no business being on the same line as the conditional :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's not really a cast. [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1033) does `value? Boolean.True: Boolean.False;` where `True` is a const of 1 and `False` is a const of zero. Still branches.

Comment: @vcsjones My mistake then; the basic premise is still there though (especially considering it likely *could* have been a cast)

Comment: The first one only does the increment if condition true. The second one always does the add (unless inlining and optimization optimizes the +0 away).

Comment: @hatchet Adding 0 isn't going to change `int`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET unless it's a custom type with an overloaded `+` operator.  (Which I would consider an unreasonable assumption given the question here, just being cute.)

Comment: @Servy I'll give you that one... and then weep at the possibility of someone doing that...

Comment: Another possibility is `int += Condition ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: The second one makes my eyes bleed. Just don't.

Comment: Why not use Linq???  `int += (new [] {Condition}).Count(a => a);`  j/k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking the clarity of the code depends on the context.

For almost all ordinary cases,

```
if (condition) i++;
```

...is going to be easier to read.

But there may be some situations like this one where the alternative makes it easier to follow.  Imagine if this list were very long:

```
var errorCount = 0
errorCount += Convert.ToInt32(o.HasAProblem);
errorCount += Convert.ToInt32(o.HasSomeOtherProblem);
errorCount += Convert.ToInt32(p.DoesntWork);
```

On the other hand, for the above, maybe I'd find a different way of structuring the code entirely, e.g.

```
var errorFlags = new [] {o.HasProblem, 
                         o.HasSomeOtherProblem, 
                         p.DoesntWork};
var errorCount = errorFlags.Count(a => a);
```

Also, the construct

```
i += Convert.ToInt32(condition);
```

...may result in a cleaner [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining) since there is no [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) involved.  The key word is *may*.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` just calls `return !value ? 0 : 1;` which involves branch.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a Boolean to an integer doesn't make any sense.

Yes, it works, because of the conversion. But it still doesn't make any sense. It's illogical.

Programs should be obvious and clear, not puzzles to be solved.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  Don't forget JavaScript! :)

Comment: Lol, no kidding

Answer (score 3):

I get 7527ms and 5888ms on my machine from the benchmark below. The first approach (boolean conversion), besides being just *awful* from a code readability point of view is also slower. That makes sense, that approach has the overhead of ALWAYS 1) performing a conversion from bool to int, and 2) performing an addition operation. Yes, there are probably shortcuts for adding "0", but that's still ANOTHER test that has to be looked at.

```
int sum = 0;

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++) {
    bool condition = i < Int32.MaxValue / 2;
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(condition);
}


sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sum = 0;
sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++) {
    bool condition = i < Int32.MaxValue / 2;
    if (condition) {
        sum++;
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many many many many ways to write code that does the same thing. But it all comes down to readability and maintainability.

You can choose to write it in binary and you will be able to optimize it in the most efficient way. But you won't find too many ppl able to maintain the code you have written. I bet not even you want to read your own code in binary when there is a bug.

so which way do you want to do it? considering that there is not that much performance gain for the 2nd method, I would say definitely go for the 1st for the sake of ppl who might be reading your code later.